# Storing login time in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

I need to store the login timings of the user in the mysql database. How do I achieve this? If possible can I store it another table. I'm using ajax for the form communication with the php.

ajaxLogin.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");
session_start();
if(isSet($_POST['username']) && isSet($_POST['password']))
{
// username and password sent from Form
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']); 
$password=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password'])); 

$result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
$_SESSION['login_user']=$row['uid'];
$sql="UPDATE users SET last_seen=now() WHERE ";
echo $row['uid'];
}

}
?>
```

Comment: you should hash your passwords in the db, not save as cleartext

Comment: Just create another table 'user_logins', with user id and time, maybe some more information like ip address etc

Comment: you have your uid, so just complete your update stmt above. So that is a stomp over with the `update`. If you want audits, do what @Coz said with `inserts` (or do both)

Comment: What issue with your code?

Comment: well @MuhammadMuazzam he is trying to finish the WHERE "  part near the end of his code

Comment: I tried  the insert command but nothing is getting displayed in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to create a new table with name "users_logins" and in every time user made a successful login(inside `if($count==1)`) make an insert to "users_logins".

"users_logins" contain:
 1. user_id
 2. login_time
 3. ip (if you want)
 4. more info.

> EDITED: example for insert into users_logins table

Create users_logins table:

```
CREATE TABLE users_logins (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    user_uid int unsigned not null,
    login_time timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(user_uid) references users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

code insert for "users_logins" table:

```
if ($count == 1) {
  $users_id = $row['uid'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users_logins (user_uid) VALUES ('$users_id')";
  if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
  }
}
```

Comment: is this correct ?
`$_SESSION['login_user']=$row['uid'];
$sql="INSERT INTO users_login(uid, login_time) VALUES($result, NOW())'";
echo $row['uid'];`

Comment: First you should create a new table with the name "users_logins".. I've edited my answer.. take a look :)

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on
if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {

Comment: Sorry, my fault.. try now

Comment: I still don't get any entries into the table 

if ($count == 1) {
  $_SESSION['login_user']=$row['uid'];
  $users_id = $row['uid'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users_logins (user_uid, login_time) VALUES ('$users_id', Now())";
  if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
  }
echo $row['uid'];
}


If I don't write session part the login system fails

Comment: How did you create users_logins table ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE users_logins (
    users_id int unsigned not null,
    login_time timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   
);

Comment: is the foreign key necessary ? As I am getting an error saying Mysql can't add the foreign key constraint

Comment: actually yea its important to not insert any wrong data(wrong user id) or not deleting an unecessary data in users_logins after deleting users.. but it can work without it.. what kind of error do you get? check that columns name in both tables and in code are same

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and patience. It's working :)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create another table `users_logins` so you will be able to have all the history of logins.

Unsigned is used to numbers greater than zero and practically you double the upper bound of acceptable integers (more info here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html). Also, be sure that `users_id` are of the same type in your `users` table. Finally, foreign keys constraints work if you have InnoDB engine otherwise delete them.

Database

```
CREATE TABLE users_logins (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    users_id int unsigned not null,
    time_created timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(users_id) references users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

PHP code:

```
if ($count == 1) {
    $users_id = $row['uid'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users_logins (users_id) VALUES ('$users_id');";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    //some other action
}
```

Comment: I don't get any entries into my table I can't understand why

Comment: Oh, yes, i had q() function instead of mysqli_query(). Now it should work fine.

Comment: is the foreign key necessary ? As I am getting an error saying Mysql can't add the foreign key constraint

Comment: Only if you want to have referential integrity. Otherwise when you delete or update a user id the old and incorrect users_id will exist in the users_logins pointing in a non existing user.

Comment: But if you want you can delete the last line including the " , " of the previous one and you will be fine.